# MS SQL: How to make sure db files are deleted when dropping a database?

Tags: sql-server, database

When my colleague drops a database he just created on SQL **2008** Express using Management Studio 2008 the files **do not** get deleted.

When I drop a database I just created on SQL **2005** Express using Management Studio 2008 the files **do** get deleted.

If my uninstaller executes a DROP DATABASE query on the same 2005 database then the files **do not** get deleted.

Is there a setting that determines if files will be deleted or what is going on?

Comment: yes! this is a feature!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How does your colleague drop the database? If he is detaching them, then they won't get deleted - perhaps he's doing that? Alternatively, if the database is offline when it's deleted then the data files **do not** get deleted. See [DROP DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178613.aspx) for more information on this.

Comment: This makes sense as my uninstaller's query to drop the database looks like this:
    "ALTER DATABASE " + dbName + " SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; DROP DATABASE " + dbName;

Comment: So after kicking out all users by setting to offline, I should probably take it back online again before dropping it.

Comment: You could also use SET SINGLE_USER or RESTRICTED_USER so you don't have to take the database offline.